# Using the rule 'classical' in Isabelle

Tags: logic, isabelle

I came across a [problem set](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/exercises/logic/propositional/ex.pdf) for natural deduction in Isabelle that uses the rule `classical`:

```
( \<not> A ==> A) ==>A
```

I am more used to using the 'law of excluded middle' (`excluded_middle`) and 'reductio ad absurdum' (`ccontr`).

I'm assuming that `classical` is equivalent to both of the above, but I can't prove either of them from it, or the `lemma "A −→ ¬ ¬ A"` which is in the problem set. I don't think I am just misunderstanding the rule, because I managed to use it successfully to prove `lemma "¬ ¬ A −→ A"` from the problem set. Could someone give me some tips/strategies/demonstrations for using this rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
lemma "A ∨ ¬ A"
proof(rule classical)
  assume "¬ (A ∨ ¬ A)"
  have "A"
  proof(rule classical)
    assume "¬ A"
    hence "(A ∨ ¬ A)" by (rule disjI2)
    with ‹¬ (A ∨ ¬ A)›
    show ?thesis by (rule notE)
  qed
  hence "(A ∨ ¬ A)" by (rule disjI1)
  with ‹¬ (A ∨ ¬ A)›
  show ?thesis by (rule notE)
qed
```

Note that `A ⟶ ¬ ¬ A` does not require classical reasoning:

```
lemma "A ⟶ ¬ ¬ A"
proof(rule impI)
  assume A
  show "¬ ¬ A"
  proof(rule notI)
    assume "¬ A"
    from this ‹A›
    show False by (rule notE)
  qed
qed
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about this since I don't understand the notation you are using (I've only used the `apply (rule classical)` style method).

Comment: I am using Isar style, the structured proof document style that you are supposed to use. But with apply scripts, it works similar, and you will have to use the same proof rules.

Answer (score 1):

Joachim Breitner's answer gave me all the information I needed, but I wanted to put it into a format that I understood better and also fitted with the problem set I originally referenced (this said to use only the `apply` method).

Here are Breitner's proofs written in this format:

```
lemma 1: "A ∨ ¬ A"
apply (rule classical)
apply (rule disjI1)
apply (rule classical)
apply (erule notE)
apply (rule disjI2)
apply assumption
done
```

'Lemma 1' I think I have shortened slightly since I did not use a second `notE` (it was unnecessary as the `A ∨ ¬ A` had already been shown).

```
lemma 2: "A ⟶ ¬ ¬ A"
apply (rule impI)
apply (rule notI)
apply (rule notE)
apply assumption
apply assumption
done
```

As Breitner points out, 'Lemma 2' does not use `classical`, and would in fact be valid in intuitionistic logic.

As for what I have learned for using the rule `classical`, one can visualise it as a kind of 'proof by contradiction': we are allowed to assume the negation and must prove our original statement.